# Precedence of operators in SQL

Tags: sql, mysql, database, postgresql, rdbms

I am using these two queries to fetch records whose salary is less than 1/10th of the 200000.

```
select first_name, last_name, salary from employee where salary < 200000 * 1/10

select first_name, last_name, salary from employee where salary < 1/10 * 200000
```

The first query gives the required output(attached below in the image). But the second query doesn't gives any record in the output(no-error).

[image]

According to my understanding of precedence in SQL both query should work in same way. That division and multiplication operator should execute first than the comparison(here <) operator.

Even, If I put parenthesis in the Second query, then also it's not giving any output.

```
select first_name, last_name, salary from employee where salary < ((1/10) * 200000)
```

So, why the Second query is not giving any output?

Comment: Because multiplication and division are performed left-to-right, in the absence of parenthesis; and 1/10 is an integer division resulting in 0. You can use cast (1 as float)/10*200000, or similar

Comment: @tinazmu Is that postgresql's behaviour ? The OP uses both mysql and postgresql tags , so I believe you might refer to the latter, as I just tested in mysql, `1/10` results in 0.1000, and both `200000 * 1/10` and `1/10 * 200000` has the same output of  20000.0000 . Furthermore, an explicit cast such as ` cast(1 as unsigned int)/10` still gets 0.1000.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql? Remove the unrelated tag.

Comment: `1 / 10` gives you 0.

Comment: @blabla_bingo; doc for v16 ways: Division (for integral types, division truncates the result towards zero). Same behaviour in many programming languages. Thank you for pointing out that MySQL (no doubt many others) don't. I answered form my experience with troubleshooting similar occurrences.

Comment: Postgresql and mysql do return different result for 1/10 https://dbfiddle.uk/iQZ4HDi9 https://dbfiddle.uk/NxgdoMqz

Answer (score 0):

When there is more than one arithmetic operator in an expression, SQL performs multiplication and division first, followed by subtraction and addition. When all arithmetic operators in an expression have the same level of precedence, the order of execution is left to right.